# My For loop won't iterate through a list

Tags: python, for-loop, math, iteration, primes

I have to determine if all the numbers in a list are prime numbers and then return a boolean "True" or "False" statement depending on the outcome. I made some conditional statements inside of a for loop to see if the number was prime or not.

Here's the code:

```
def all_primes(xs):
    is_prime = None
    for i in xs:
        if i < 2:
            is_prime = False
            return is_prime
            break
        elif (i % 2 == 0) and (i % i == 1):
            is_prime = False
            return is_prime
            break
        else:
            is_prime = True
            return is_prime
```

The problem is, and I saw this in the Python Visualizer, the for loop stops iterating after checking the first value in the list. I don't understand why as the syntax is the same as for loops I've used in the past.

I plugged in some example values like: `all_primes([5,2,11,37])` or `all_primes([5,2,4,37])` and the return value is always true since 5 is the first number on the list and the only number that is being iterated.

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: You have `return` in each of your branches. That immediately breaks out of the function. You need to set up your code to `return` after your `for` loop has completed.

Comment: Additionally, `i % i`is always 0, so the `and`-statement of the first `elif` can never be true.

Comment: Ah I didn't catch that. Would that mean I have to get rid of the breaks as well? I am using the breaks because the loop needs to close as soon as even a single value is not prime.

Comment: @ChristianKönig ah yeah, I meant to say divide "/" rather than mod "%"

Comment: @PrithviBoinpally `i / i` would make no sense either

Comment: @khelwood It's to check if a number is divisible by 1 and itself. I guess it's redundant because a negative number is already filtered out before.

Comment: @PrithviBoinpally You really should check your logic to decide, if a number is prime. With the current implementation (ignoring the `i%i` or `i/i`) every odd number would be prime.

Comment: @khelwood _Any_ whole number is divisible by 1 and itself. The special thing about primes is, that there are no _other_ numbers.

Comment: @ChristianKönig I just realized that as well, so If i were to approach this, would I really have to be doing a composite test rather than a prime test? How would I check to see of an odd number is not prime?

Comment: @PrithviBoinpally https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Comment: @ChristianKönig What are you telling me for? I said `i / i` was wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a `return` and a `break` in your `if/else` block, you should get rid of them. Also the `return` in the `else` should be outside, or it will just return whenever he finds a "prime".

```
def all_primes(xs):
  is_prime = None
  for i in xs:
      if i < 2:
          is_prime = False
          return is_prime
      elif (i % 2 == 0):
          is_prime = False
          return is_prime
      else:
          is_prime = True
  return is_prime
```

After this, you should know, that you are not really checking primes.
Here is not the most efficient way but its clear how to:

```
def all_primes(xs):
    def checkPrime(n):
        if n < 2:
            return False
        for i in xrange(2, n):
            if n%i == 0:
                return False
        return True
    return all(map(checkPrime, xs))
```

EDIT:
without the `map` functions, you just have to iterate with a `for` loop:

```
def all_primes(xs):
    def checkPrime(n):
        if n < 2:
            return False
        for i in xrange(2, n):
            if n%i == 0:
                return False
        return True
    for n in xs:
        if not checkPrime(n):
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: How would I write the code you suggested without using the "map" function?

Comment: I tried the edited code but unfortunately there are some test cases that don't work with that logic. If the list's input was 1,3,5,7 then it would fail because 1 is not a prime number and neither is a negative number.

Comment: @PrithviBoinpally, just add the check in the checkPrime function, will edit again.

Answer (score 1):

You should see the problem the other way around.

If you you find a number which is not prime you should return False, and after your loop end you should return True.